# Rails Reset seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a dropdown menu database of categories in my seeds.rb file and accidentally did rake db:seed another time to add duplicate categories.  Being a noob, I'd like to know what's the best way in a development ENV to make the category dropdown reset and put back the following categories...

seeds.rb

```
Category.create(name: 'General')
Category.create(name: 'Birthday')
Category.create(name: 'Sports and Recreation')
Category.create(name: 'Music')
Category.create(name: 'Nature')
Category.create(name: 'Education')
Category.create(name: 'Political')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend your seeds.rb file with `Category.destroy_all`. This will instantiate and destroy all your categories.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't want duplicates, you can fall back to:

```
Category.find_or_create_by_name('General')
```

This will attempt to find it (by name), or create the record if it doesn't exist.